# changing time format in node js

Tags: node.js, datetime, date-formatting

Here I am fetching the date stored in the database in format(2013-08-17 07:50:21), I am getting the below output, But I need the date in format like 17 August 2013 without using any third party module. Is it possible? If yes suggest the solution.

```
 var sql2 ="SELECT `user_id`, `vote_date` FROM `tb_post_votes` WHERE `post_id`=?";
  connection.query(sql2,[postId],function(err, result) {

  var post={"user_id":result[0].user_id,"date":result[0].vote_date}); 
    res.send(JSON.stringify(post));               
   }); 

Output: {"user_id":11,"date":"2013-08-17T07:50:21.000Z"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript / nodejs does not give a format method for Date objects. However you can easily get the date, month and year from provided native methods...

```
getYear()       - gives year count from 1990 113 for 2013
getFullYear()   - gives full year as 2013
getMonth()      - gives month number 0 based index
getDate()       - gives date of the month
```

also `new Date()` takes date in different formats and convert it into the local date/time one of which is UTC date format. So if your node server is at UTC time then you can directly convert the date with the `Date` constructor.

```
var date = new Date(UTC_Date);
```

for your specification we can use `getMonth()` in conjunction with an [`Array`](http://nodemanual.org/latest/js_doc/Array.html) of months.

This should work for you...

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
    "July", "August","September", "October", "November", "December"];

var date = new Date(result[0].vote_date);

var dateStr = date.getDate() +' '
            + months[date.getMonth()] +' '
            + date.getFullYear();

console.log(dateStr); // gives 17 August 2013
var post={"user_id":result[0].user_id,"date":dateStr});
```

You may also find [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/1618713) and [Working with Dates](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/) useful.